# x path not counting second element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i have a xpath set to search for the first and second heading however the second comes up as blank, im guessing this must be pretty easy however ive tried changing the path names so many times and i cant seem to solve it, i then used a for each to find out if maybe my xml file was incorrect but my  loop seems to find both with ease.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foo="blogschema.xsd"
exclude-result-prefixes="foo">
<xsl:output method ="html" indent ="no"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blogStyle.css"/>
    <body>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class ="Part 1"><xsl:value-of select="//foo:Heading[1]"/> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class ="Part 2"><xsl:value-of select="//foo:Heading[2]"/></a></li>
    </ul>






        <div id="heading">

        <xsl:for-each select="//foo:Entry">
        <!--<xsl:sort select="Heading"/> -->


        <div class ="topNavigation"><a href="#home"><h3><xsl:value-of    select="foo:Heading"/></h3></a></div>

        </xsl:for-each>
        <div class ="panes">




        </div>

        </div>
        <div id ="blogpicture">
            <div class="picture">
                <div id="headerTitle"><h2><xsl:value-of        select="//foo:Title"/></h2></div>
                </div>
                </div>


    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

im trying to get a menu but all im getting right now is part 1 of the menu, in the for loop i can get part 2.A alternative could be to stick to using the loop, and as i'm looping change the class somehow during the loop(incrment the class id)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    My blog

```
<Entry>
    <Heading id="101">Part 1</Heading>  
    <body>
        <text>something interesting</text>
        <pictures>pictures in the body</pictures>
        <videos>Videos in the body</videos>
    </body>
    <labels>Seperate labels with commas</labels>
    <date> 20121119</date>
    <location>The location the blog was published</location>

</Entry>

<Entry>
    <Heading id="102">Part 2</Heading>
        <body>
            <text>something</text>
            <pictures>pictures in the body</pictures>
            <videos>Videos in the body</videos>
        </body>
    <labels>Seperate labels with commas</labels>
    <date> 2012-11-26Z</date>
    <location>The location the blog was published</location>

</Entry>


<author>me</author>
```

i hope this makes some sense
the output im currently getting in the menu u is part 1 and then "" for where i'm meant to have part 2. The for each loop in the xsl however brings part 1 and 2 headings

Comment: Could you format your code to be more readable please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<li><a href="#" class ="Part 1"><xsl:value-of select="//foo:Entry[1]/foo:Heading"/> </a></li>
<li><a href="#" class ="Part 2"><xsl:value-of select="//foo:Entry[2]/foo:Heading"/></a></li>
```

Alternatively, this should work too:

```
<li><a href="#" class ="Part 1"><xsl:value-of select="(//foo:Heading)[1]"/> </a></li>
<li><a href="#" class ="Part 2"><xsl:value-of select="(//foo:Heading)[2]"/></a></li>
```

From the almighty [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-context-position):

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select any para element in the document (even a para element that is a document element will be selected by `//para` since the document element node is a child of the root node); `div//para` is short for `div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select all para descendants of div children.
>
> NOTE: The location path `//para[1]` does *not* mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe this worked fine. Pretty confusing how "part 1" was able to work in the first place by reading your answer

Comment: If you read it close enough it makes sense.  `//_something_[_number_]` matches all the `something`s that are the `number`th child of their parent element.  Since both `foo:Heading`s are the first child of their parent, `//foo:Heading[1]` matches _both_ of them and then the `<xsl:value-of>` directive selected the first one of those in the document.

Comment: Still seems a bit magical to me - I know the spec says it is so, but it doesn't say _why_ the content of [number] is different for // and /descendant::. Any thoughts?

Comment: The important thing is the axis where the `[]` is being applied. If you look at the expanded version of `//foo:heading[2]` you get `/descandant-or-self::node()/child::foo:heading[2]`, or in other words, all the second `foo:heading` _children_ of any node. In the case of `/descendant::foo:heading[2]`, the axis is the descendant axis, and this selects the second `foo:heading` descendant of the document root.