# How do I get the nth element with a certain name in the entire XML document?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath, hpple

so will something like this work using Hpple Xpath

```
//a[4]
```

The fourth  tag in a html tree?
Or do i need to do it programmatically by counting in a for() loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath for the fourth `<a>` in an HTML document is:

```
(//a)[4]
```

Your example `//a[4]` will produce a set of all `<a>`s that are the fourth `<a>` in their respective parent, and that is not what you want here.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209492/1945651

Comment: wait so will this work //table[@class='grid']/tbody/(tr)[4]/(td)[16]

Comment: That's not valid XPath, but what are you trying to accomplish with it?  It would be valid without the parentheses, but is there only one `grid` table on the page or several? If there are several, do you want to access all of them, or just one?

Comment: //table[@class='grid']/tbody/tr[4]/td[16] So would this work to access only that specific box on the table.

Comment: Yes, assuming there is only one table with a `class` attribute value of "grid".