# XSLT 2.0 breaks my stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a stylesheet that I developed in version 1.0.  I needed to convert to version 2.0 to take advantage of some additional features.  Now however, when I use the following syntax I get all the results instead of just the first one.  This worked  in v1.0 but does not work in v2.0:

```
//elementName[1]
```

Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Can you provide a small [snippet](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/YLse87/2) of the document and stylesheet which reproduces the problem, and also specify the names of the 2 processors you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the nth element of a certain name in the entire XML document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664001/how-do-i-get-the-nth-element-of-a-certain-name-in-the-entire-xml-document)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That XPath will return the same nodes in both versions (namely all the `elementName` elements in the document that are the first child with that name in their respective parent elements), but

```
<xsl:value-of select="//elementName[1]"/>
```

will give different results. In XSLT 1.0 the behaviour of `value-of` when given a set of nodes is to output the value of the first node in the set in document order and ignore the others, but in 2.0 it will output the values of *all* of them, separated by spaces. If you want to restrict to the first item in the sequence you should do so explicitly with `(....)[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the fix is simple...

```
(//elementName)[1]
```

This will give you the first occurrence. Your previous xpath was every `elementName` that was the first `elementName` child of its parent.

A good example from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> NOTE: The location path //para[1] does *not* mean the same as the
>   location path /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first
>   descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para
>   elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Comment: `//elementName[1]` should exhibit no difference between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. If it's behaving differently, then he's probably working with a buggy XPath 1.0 engine.

Comment: No difference in template matches, but when using `value-of`: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLV/5.